# Trouble filtering Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Story:
We have 3 different tables. TimeReport, Dossier, BU
The first one is connected to the second one, one to many.
The second one is connected to the third one, one to many.
[image: see picture db.png]

We wanted to use a radgrid component to display 'TimeReports'.
We built in filters for example for 'DossierId' and are displaying the property 'Description'.
This works fine.

Our problem is now that we want to display and filter for example BU.BUId and BU.Code.
We tried this several ways, with java script or in code behind.
Unfortunately it doesn't work.
The problem seems to be that we want access the properties over two tables. (from 'TimeReport' over 'Dossier' to 'BU')

```
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Dossier.BU.Code" FilterControlAltText="Filter BUId column" 
    HeaderText="BU" SortExpression="BUId" UniqueName="BUId"> 
    <FilterTemplate> 
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBoxTitle" DataSourceID="dsBU" DataTextField="Code" 
            DataValueField="BUId" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnPreRender="RadComboBoxTitle_PreRender" 
            runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBoxTitle_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
            <Items> 
                <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="All" /> 
            </Items> 
        </telerik:RadComboBox> 
    </FilterTemplate> 
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Code behind

```
protected void RadComboBoxTitle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    RadComboBox buCombo = sender as RadComboBox; 

    ViewState["buComboValue"] = buCombo.SelectedValue; 

    TimeReportGrid.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = "(it.[Dossier.BUId] = " + buCombo.SelectedValue + ")"; 
    GridColumn column = TimeReportGrid.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("BUId"); 
    column.CurrentFilterFunction = GridKnownFunction.EqualTo; 
    column.CurrentFilterValue = buCombo.SelectedValue; 
    TimeReportGrid.Rebind(); 
} 
protected void RadComboBoxTitle_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (ViewState["buComboValue"] != null) 
    { 
        RadComboBox buCombo = sender as RadComboBox; 
        buCombo.SelectedValue = ViewState["buComboValue"].ToString(); 
    } 
}
```

This Code throws an error on "TimeReportGrid.Rebind()".

**'Dossier.BUId' is not a member of type 'Model.TimeReport' in the currently loaded schemas. Near escaped identifier, line 6, column 5.**

Feel free to ask questions if necessary.

Thanks for your help and fast answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are running into a problem where your EntityFramework objects are disconnected from the database when you are filtering and rebinding and they cannot lazy-load the content that you are attempting to filter on.  Try using an [Include()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) statement in the initial query that loads the grid so that the tables you do want to filter on are available in the disconnected collection that is being filtered.

---

Code Sample - with the following Code-First Entity Framework objects:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<TimeReport> TimeReport { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Dossier> Dossier { get; set; }

    public DbSet<BU> BU { get; set; }

}

public class BU
{

    public int BUId { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

}

public class Dossier
{

    public int DossierId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BU")]
    public int BUId { get; set; }

    public BU BU { get; set; }

}

public class TimeReport
{

    public int TimeReportId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Dossier")]
    public int DossierId { get; set; }

    public Dossier Dossier { get; set; }

}
```

I am able to re-write your FilterExpression on the MasterTableView of the RadGrid to:

```
TimeReportGrid.MasterTableView.FilterExpression = "(it.Dossier.BUId = " + buCombo.SelectedValue + ")";
```

and that connection works.

Check this link for more information about how to [customize FilterExpression](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-operate-with-filter-expression-manually.html) for the [RadGrid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx)